# How to use a global variable between two describe method in cypress?

Tags: javascript, automation, scope, cypress, global-variables

I have 2 describe's with one global variable.
I'm initialising the global varibale on 1st describe, i need to use the same value on the 2nd describe

I have tried this but it's printing "" on the 2nd describe

[image: please check the screenshot here]

```js
var value 
describe("group 1", function() { 
  it('test 1', function(){ 
    value = 5 
    cy.log(value) 
  }) 
}) 
describe("group 2", function() { 
  it('test 2', function() { 
    cy.log(value) 
    cy.wrap(value).should('eq', 5) 
  }) 
})
```

Comment: Sorry, we [can't accept images of code, data or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Post those as *text*, so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything, and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.

Comment: I tried out your test, but it didn't fail. I used latest Cypress v12.8.0. Any idea why that is?

Answer (score 4):

Please try with `testIsolation: false` in the configuration.

Ref: [Test Isolation](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/core-concepts/test-isolation)

> Cypress supports enabling or disabling test isolation in end-to-end testing to describe if a suite of tests should run in a clean browser context or not.

This is the bullet point causing your issue:

> When test isolation is enabled, Cypress resets the browser context before each test by:
>
> - clearing the dom state by visiting about:blank

Go to `cypress.config.js` and add `testIsolation: false`.

This will allow your global to carry over to the next test.